# Determine compressed/uncompressed buffer size for Z-lib in C

Tags: c, zlib

I'm using Zlib v1.2.7 to read a text file then compress it and write it to an output file. My problem is in the following example how can I determine the output buffer size based on input size? (in the example `gz_length`)
I'm using this library for an STM32 Device. I added the unzip method and I have this problem as well for uncompressed data length.

```
#include "zlib.h"

int unzip(unsigned char *dst, unsigned long *dst_length, unsigned char *src, unsigned long src_length)
{
    z_stream stream;
    memset(&stream, 0, sizeof(stream));

    stream.next_in = src;
    stream.avail_in = src_length;

    stream.next_out = dst;
    stream.avail_out = *dst_length;

    int rv = inflateInit2(&stream, 15 + 16);
    if (Z_OK == rv) {
        rv = inflate(&stream, Z_NO_FLUSH);
        if (Z_STREAM_END == rv) {
            inflateEnd(&stream);
            rv = Z_OK;
        }
    }

    if (Z_OK == rv) {
        *dst_length = stream.total_out;
    } else {
        *dst_length = 0;
    }

    return rv;
}


int zip(unsigned char *dst, unsigned long *dst_length, unsigned char *src, unsigned long src_length)
{
    z_stream        stream;
    memset(&stream, 0, sizeof(stream));

    stream.next_in = src;
    stream.avail_in = src_length;

    stream.next_out = Z_NULL;
    stream.avail_out = 0;

    /* add 16 to MAX_WBITS to specify gzip format - it gets taken off again in defaultInit2 */
    int rv = deflateInit2(&stream, Z_DEFAULT_COMPRESSION, Z_DEFLATED, 16 + MAX_WBITS, MAX_MEM_LEVEL, Z_DEFAULT_STRATEGY);
    if (Z_OK == rv) {
        unsigned long dst_bound = deflateBound(&stream, stream.avail_in) + 12; /* 12 bytes for the gzip header */
        if (dst_bound > *dst_length) {
            rv = Z_MEM_ERROR;
        } else {
            stream.next_out   = dst;
            stream.avail_out = dst_bound;
        }
    }

    if (Z_OK == rv) {
        gz_header        header;
        memset(&header, 0, sizeof(header));
        rv = deflateSetHeader(&stream, &header);
    }

    if (Z_OK == rv) {
        rv = deflate(&stream, Z_FINISH);
        if (Z_STREAM_END == rv) {
            rv = deflateEnd(&stream);
        }
    }

    if (Z_OK == rv) {
        *dst_length = stream.total_out;
    } else {
        *dst_length = 0;
    }

    return rv;
}

int main()
{
    unsigned long read_size;
    unsigned char *buffer = NULL;
    unsigned char *gz_buffer = NULL;
    unsigned long input_size = 0;

    /* Open your_file in read-only mode */
    FILE *fp = fopen("/local/new.txt", "r");
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END); /* Go to end of file */
    input_size = ftell(fp); /* How many bytes did we pass ? */
    printf("Filesize: %ld\n", input_size);
    /* Set position of stream to the beginning */
    rewind(fp);
    /* Allocate the buffer (no need to initialize it with calloc) */
    buffer = (unsigned char*) malloc((input_size + 1) * sizeof(*buffer)); /* input_size + 1 byte for the \0 */
    /* Read the file into the buffer */
    fread(buffer, input_size, 1, fp); /* Read 1 chunk of input_size bytes from fp into buffer */
    /* NULL-terminate the buffer */
    buffer[input_size] = '\0';
    /* Print it ! */
    printf("FileData: %s\n", buffer);
    fclose(fp);
    //PROBLEM HERE how to determine valid gz_length for output based on input_size
    unsigned long gz_length = input_size + 50;
    gz_buffer = (unsigned char*) malloc((gz_length) * sizeof(*gz_buffer));

    if (input_size > 0)
    {
        int rv = zip(gz_buffer, &gz_length, buffer, input_size);
        if (Z_OK == rv)
        {
            FILE *ofp = fopen("/local/out.gz", "w");
            if (ofp)
            {
                int bw = fwrite(gz_buffer, 1, gz_length, ofp);
                fclose(ofp);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            printf("%s:%d: %d%s", __FILE__, __LINE__, rv, newline);
        }
    }
    free(buffer);
    free(gz_buffer);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to compress in a single `deflate()` call (which is not necessary by the way), zlib provides the function `deflateBound()` for exactly this purpose.

There is no useful bound in the other direction. By not useful, I mean that the bound on the size of the decompressed output is over a thousand times the size of the compressed input.

Comment: @Thanks. I found [this example](https://github.com/madler/zlib/blob/master/examples/zpipe.c) useful but Is there any difference between one deflate and multiple deflations?

Comment: There is no difference in the results. For large streams, there is a lot of difference in how much memory is required.